# I wonder why there are different results from errors when I use express, axios, and cors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-crawler

When i'm crawling to my college site of one part, there is error.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (localhost:3000/:1)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:99)
```

I've tried other things but I'm not sure why it is getting shows 'Load...' and in the console there is error.

The site is working but crawling is not working properly and showing 'Load...'

this is **kangnam.js** :

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const log = console.log;
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const getHTML = async () => {
    try {
        return await axios.get('https://web.kangnam.ac.kr', {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'text/html'
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    getHTML()
        .then(html => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html.data);
        const $allNotices = $("ul.tab_listl div.list_txt");

        let resultArr = [];
        $allNotices.each(function(idx, element) {
            let itemObj = {
                title : $(this).children('a').attr('title'),
                url : $(this).children('a').attr('href'),
            };
            resultArr.push(itemObj);
        });
        
        resultArr.forEach((element) => {
            console.log(`현재 ${element._title}의 현황 : ${element._url}`);
        });
        return resultArr;

        // const data = ulList.filter(n => n.title);
        // return data;
    }). then((data) => res.send(data));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => 
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

this is **NoticesList.js** :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import NoticesItem from './NoticesItem';
import axios from "axios";

const NoticesListBlock = styled.div`
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
    width: 768px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
`;

const sampleArticle = {
    title: 'title',
    url: 'https://google.com',
};

const NoticesList = () => {
    
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async() => {
            const datas = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/");
            setData(datas.data);
        };
        getData();
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data);
    }, [data]);
    
    if(data === null){
        return <div>Load....</div>;
    }else{
        console.log(data);
        return (
            <div>
                {data.map((ele) => (
                    <>
                        <div>
                            {ele.title};
                        </div>
                    <br/>
                    </>
                ))}
            </div>  
        );
    };

    
    
};

export default NoticesList;
```

this is **NoticesItem.js** :

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const NoticesItemBlock = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    .contents {
        h6 {
            margin: 15px;
            a {
                color: black;
            }
        }
    }
    & + & {
        margin-top: 1.5rem;
    }
`;

const NoticesItem = ({ article }) => {
    const { title, url } = article;
    return (
        <NoticesItemBlock>
            <div className="contents">
                <h6>
                    <a href={url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                        {title}
                    </a>
                </h6>
            </div>
        </NoticesItemBlock>
    );
};

export default NoticesItem;
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're starting your local server on port 4000 but fetching localhost:3000

Comment: @ibsn  I edited `const datas = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/");` to `const datas = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/");`  But the error is same...

the error is :

`GET http://localhost:4000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:99)`

Comment: Could it be because you are trying to access a HTTP resource from a HTTPS page?

Comment: @Sterex then what should i do?

Comment: @Sterex Can you modify my code remotely?

Comment: Your server code is running on port 4000, but in NoticesList component you requested to port 3000.
Besides, the error is clear `Network Error` that means cannot connect to the server, in this case, no server is running on port 3000,

Comment: @박종준 you should replace string `http://localhost:3000/` in file `NoticesList.js` to be `http://localhost:4000/`

Comment: @ Trần Đức Huy I did bit error is same

Comment: @박종준 You can try using HTTPS for all services. --> https://localhost:3000

Comment: @Sterex can u tell me what should i do and whats the problem??

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help you beyond this. Try checking: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Answer (score 0):

try deploying an API on goormide, just change the last part of kangnam.js for:

```
app.listen(3000, function() { 
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000'); 
});
```

this will give a link like: https://server-clgoz.run-eu-central1.goorm.io/
wich you will use instead of: http://localhost:4000/
on NoticesList.js

Also in this file you can set a variable like:

```
const site="https://web.kangnam.ac.kr/";
```

and then in the map function:

```
<a href={site+decodeURIComponent(ele.url.slice(17))}>{ele.title}</a>
```

this will give the links to the site.

Good luck :) !!!